# How to add listener to stateless bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, event-listener

Obviously, the bean is Stateless so it can't retain information like a listener added to it. But I need it to be able to alert a containing class (where the stateless bean is injected into) when an event occurs. How could I go about doing this?

**Edit:** The containing class of the Stateless bean is a Servlet.

Comment: If I might recall servlets correctly, they don't live "on their own" but rather only when a request is being mapped onto them - does this comply with your assumption of a "long living" servlet?

Comment: @Smutje, the way I understand Servlets, is that the container will create a single instance of one. Then there will be a dedicated thread per connection to the servlet. In particular, I'm using an "Asynchronous Servlet" to recycle threads for other use until I have something to send the client (long-polling technique). I then need this Servlet to listen for an event, to know when to send a client information. I'll try implementing the Extension interface, see where that goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CDI event in your stateless bean to fire when a certain condition is matched and your containing class can `@Observes` this event and therefore react on the event.

## Example:

### StringEvent.java

```
public class StringEvent {

    private final String string;

    public StringEvent(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return this.string;
    }
}
```

### SBean.java

```
@Stateless
public class SBean {

    @Inject
    Event<StringEvent> stringEvent;

    public void m() {
        this.stringEvent.fire(new StringEvent("Event happening!"));
    }
}
```

### Handler.java

```
public class Handler {

    public void m(@Observes StringEvent stringEvent) {
        System.out.println(stringEvent.getString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have stated that the containing class will be a Servlet. which Observes states it can only be applied to a parameter of a method belonging to a bean or extension class. Therefore, I don't believe the Observer pattern would work directly. Any way around this you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

So, to fix my problem I merely, created a listener Interface which I had my Servlet implement. I then changed my Stateless EJB to Stateful (because, obviously, the stateless can't hold a listener object) and made it Application Scoped. Then, I added my Servlet class to a list within the EJB. When an event occurred, my EJB would call all the Interfaces, within the lists, corresponding methods.